# Cannot install Drupal 8 theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-8

[Install Drupal 8 Theme Simple Process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdD94PUDnsk) I want to install a new theme in Drupal 8, but at the end of the installation it gives me an error saying:

> does not contain any .info.yml files

even though it is a Drupal 8 theme.
Is there a way that I manually can create `.info.yml` file or any other solution?

Comment: You're probably trying to install a theme that's compatible with Drupal 7 or lower. There's no magic upgrade path, it'll need to be rewritten for Drupal 8 (pretty significant changes)

Comment: I was trying to install a theme that's compatible with Drupal 8. Here is the link of the theme [link](http://www.weebpal.com/drupal-themes/zircon-responsive-drupal-8-theme)

Comment: Oh right, you should contact the developer of the theme and submit a bug report. If the compatibility details are accurate, that theme is pretty out of date now

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33392870/1941316) solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an info.yml file.

The method you followed export the zip file that contains the theme and let Drupal handle the rest.

The zip file you downloaded does not contain directly the theme, but also some other files.

Solution: Extract your zip file, and upload just the zip that contains your theme, in your case "zircon_d8-8.1.1".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the info.yml file though, at themes/zircon/ you have the theme file: zircon.info.yml

Answer (score 0):

Check that your files installed properly.  I tried to look at the Zip file from the Zircon site but it was a bit odd and had two sub folders each compressed (the theme itself zircon_d8-8.0.0.zip which I couldn't open and zircon_d8-demo-8.0.0.zip which has a full drupal install).  If you look in the folder zircon_d8-demo-8.0.0.zip\zircon_d8\themes you'll see the folder zircon.  That's probably the file you need.  For what it's worth The zircon.info.yml file begins:

```
name: Zircon
type: theme
base theme: classy
description: 'A flexible, recolorable theme with many regions and a responsive, mobile-first layout.'
package: Core
version: 8.0.0
core: 8.x
...
```

Which looks fine to me.  Don't know why they messed up.