# Theme installation in drupal 8 Fails

Tags: drupal-theming, drupal-8

i am a newbie in drupal. I installed drupal then tried to change the theme i tried three themes. Everytime i get the same error `zircon_profile-8.x-1.0-beta11.zip does not contain any .info.yml files.` name of the theme changes only. Am i missing any thing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I tried getting themes from this site http://www.weebpal.com/free-drupal-themes.

I followed steps from this site http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-8/themes/upload-new
went to Apperance then selected Install new theme, then choosed the file (zip) from my system and then clicked install.

Comment: Have you been able to install a Weebpal theme following instructions in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weebpal Zircon theme does not work as usual contributed theme, it needs additional database tables. To install it, you have to specifically follow instructions in the [Weebpal Step by Step Guide to Install Drupal 8 Theme](http://www.weebpal.com/guides/step-step-guide-install-drupal-8-theme).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the other two themes, but zircon only works up to alpha 11.
https://www.drupal.org/project/zircon